# How to remove new line characters from data rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, trim

I can loop through all of the rows in a php script and do

`UPDATE mytable SET title = "'.trim($row['title']).'" where id = "'.$row['id'].'";`

and trim can remove \n

But I was just wondering if something same could be done in one query?

```
 update mytable SET title = TRIM(title, '\n') where 1=1
```

will it work? I can then just execute this query without requiring to loop through!

thanks

(PS: I could test it but table is quite large and dont want to mess with data, so just thought if you have tested something like this before)

Comment: You can just get rid of the where clause...be careful w/ your trim though because you might have other characters in the set (like carriage return '\r')

Comment: You should have tested that before you ask this question. It works. If you want to test that on big table you can use LIMIT clause.

Comment: Whats wrong with the WHERE clause? Just curious

Comment: @PhillPafford Nothing, technically, it's just redundant.  (I know this is >5 years old, but might help other people coming to read it.)

Comment: Some DB/SQL Tools warn you (rightfully!) when you try to execute an `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause. This `where 1=1` looks an awful lot like a way to bypass this check. I would avoid that. @PhillPafford @Bing

Answer (score 137, accepted):

your syntax is wrong:

```
update mytable SET title = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM title)
```

**Addition:**

If the newline character is at the start of the field:

```
update mytable SET title = TRIM(LEADING '\n' FROM title)
```

Comment: coming from MSSQL, this syntax was very foreign to me. i thought you were using pseudocode! but it worked :)

Comment: Documentation on [TRIM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) for reference.

Answer (score 152):

```
UPDATE test SET log = REPLACE(REPLACE(log, '\r', ''), '\n', '');
```

worked for me.

while its similar, it'll also get rid of \r\n

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/182689

Comment: this does not remove trailing \n, it removes all \n, which is not desired here.

Comment: This may not have worked for the exact OP, but did help in a sitch I was dealing with, +1

Comment: exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 20):

1) Replace all **new line** and **tab** characters with spaces.

2) Remove all **leading and trailing** spaces.

```
 UPDATE mytable SET `title` = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`title`, '\n', ' '), '\r', ' '), '\t', ' '));
```

Answer (score 12):

`update mytable set title=trim(replace(REPLACE(title,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),''));`

Above is working for fine.

Comment: This one is useful when '\n' is not working (tested on mysql workbench)

Answer (score 8):

Removes trailing returns when importing from Excel. When you execute this, you may receive an error that there is no WHERE; ignore and execute.

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM col_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE mytable SET title=TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(title, "\n", ""), "\t", ""));
```

Comment: this does not remove trailing \n, it removes all \n, which is not desired here.

Answer (score 3):

Playing with above answers, this one works for me

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(column_name , '\n', ''), '\r', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents.

To get rid of my \n's I needed to do a \\n. Hope that helps someone.

```
update mytable SET title = TRIM(TRAILING '\\n' FROM title)
```

Answer (score 0):

For new line characters

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM field_name);
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM field_name);
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\r\n' FROM field_name);
```

For all white space characters

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = TRIM(field_name);
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM field_name);
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM field_name);
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\r\n' FROM field_name);
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\t' FROM field_name);
```

Read more:
[MySQL TRIM Function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-trim)