# Replace newline characters in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, with two column: `id, text`
I would like to replace the newline characters to spaces in the text column.

```
UPDATE txt SET text=REPLACE(text, '\n', ' ') WHERE text LIKE %\n%
```

Will this work? I want to be sure, before I run this code. I don't like to crash my table, because I have a lot of data in it.

Comment: backup the table then test, or create a table with fake data and test, or better yet read the documentation and see what it says `REPLACE` will do, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504962/how-to-remove-new-line-characters-from-data-rows-in-mysql

Comment: *" I want to be sure, before I run this code"* take care that we sometimes have some troll that tell you what to use instead - remember it's the internet. So better look how you can test that your own without loosing anything. That's way better. You will enable yourself to solve all sorts of problems (hence the DV, asking a question that way is not constructive because it's a psychological problem (in the first-hand) of yours, not a programming question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find at least one row id which has data with `\n` in it:

```
SELECT id, text FROM txt
WHERE text LIKE '%\n%'
LIMIT 1
```

Take a note of `id`, remember it.
Then, try to replace it using your query:

```
UPDATE txt SET text=REPLACE(text, '\n', ' ')
WHERE id = 123
  AND text LIKE '%\n%'
```

Now, check if your update was successful (it should show empty result):

```
SELECT id, text FROM txt
WHERE text LIKE '%\n%'
  AND id = 123
```

If it worked fine, run the same update, but now without limits.

If anything went wrong, you might have corrupted just one row which id and text you have seen in first step, so it should be easy to fix back.

Answer (score 0):

First take a Back up of table **`txt`**.

```
select
*
into tt_txt_2013_07_28
from txt
```

Now find the `count` of records `where text LIKE %\n%`

```
select count(*)
from txt
where text LIKE %\n%
```

Note the `count`

Now you can run the Update Query and match the count. If you have any bad result you can take the backup the records from back-up table  `tt_txt_2013_07_28`

```
UPDATE txt 
SET text=REPLACE(text, '\n', ' ') 
WHERE text LIKE %\n%
```