# NIH UMLS Data Model on MRREL

Tags: mysql, medical

I am working with the Unified Medical Language System (UMLS)  database within a local copy of MySQL.  I am currently attempting to understand the data structures via this webpage: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9685/

I am attempting to identify concepts in CUI2.  However, I am confused by this result:

```
SELECT y.* FROM mrrel r INNER JOIN mrconso y ON r.cui2 = y.CUI;
```

Exactly 1 result.  Rather than wildly speculate—is it my sql?  is it an error on the tables? did I misunderstand the schema?—I would really appreciate some feedback from the UMLS community. How do I correctly link MRREL.cui2 to other tables within the database?  Is there a COMPLETE data model published somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: For posterity, I have found a clue.  The MRREL, MRSTY and MRSCONSO tables all had leading "\n" characters in the CUI fields.  In MRREL only in CUI1, not CUI2. I will comment again if that solves the problem.  I fixed that by using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504962/how-to-remove-new-line-characters-from-data-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian,

Not knowing anything about how you created your subset, I modified your query a bit and ran it against a full Metathesaurus subset from the 2015AA release.

`SELECT count(DISTINCT y.cui)
FROM mrrel r 
INNER JOIN mrconso y ON r.cui2 = y.CUI
;`

I got back 3074046 unique CUIs.  Perhaps you can send me your mmsys.log file to make sure that your subset completed properly?  Also, you can several ER diagrams and [sample queries on our website](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/implementation_resources/query_diagrams/index.html) that could help in understanding the RRF data model.  Also, how many total rows are in your MRREL table?

Comment: I am running on 2015AA.  I have 27,612,106 in mrrel.  This query still brings nothing, but I'm making sure I have no more leading/trailing characters.

Comment: Another clue, the MRCONSO table has all but one CUIs as bit_length 56, where all but one CUI2 of MRSTY is > 56.  <code> select count(*) from mrrel where bit_length(cui2) > 56; </code> Playing with that, only one of MRCONSO.CUI should match MRSTY.CUI2.  I'm afraid I don't understand the data model.

Comment: With the help of user3653270 I did a complete reinstall.  The newlines and bit length problems were corrected.