# MySQL simple query returns zero rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table Types that has the following columns: ID, Name, Type. The table is filled with about 300 rows. One of the rows:

```
ID    Name    Type
------------------
1     BMW     S 1000 RR
```

The following query returns this row:

```
SELECT * FROM Types WHERE Name = 'BMW'
```

However, the following query returns nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM Types WHERE Type = 'S 1000 RR'
```

There are no extra spaces in the Type, and the data types of Name and Type are exactly the same (varchar 255, utf8_unicode_ci). What can possibly cause this?

I am using MySQL, InnoDB. Using phpMyAdmin I get the exact same results, so no typo's in column names...

Comment: I find it very surprising that the query is working at all in either case. `types` and `type` are both MySQL reserved words and shouldn't really have worked without backtick escaping.

Comment: @apokryfos that is not correct. Niether of them is Reserved and niether of them requires backticks

Comment: @HankyPanky [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) seems to claim otherwise

Comment: @apokryfos No, it shows they are key words, and not reserved.

Comment: @apokryfos do you see an `(R)` infront of either of those terms? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e48d6/1

Comment: Check in database whtr S 1000 RR has spaces on either sides?

Comment: Hmm @apokryfos, was too eager, this did not fix my problem. There are no spaces on either side. TRIM(Type) also did not work.

I am guessing there is a newline in the value somewhere, as I read the Types line per line from a text file... But this shouldn't show up in the varchar value.

Comment: Would `WHERE Type LIKE 'S 1000 RR'` fare any better?

Comment: I've found the problem: it was indeed a newline character that doesn't show up in the browse view of phpMyAdmin. When editing the row, I could see that there was an 'enter', a newline in the value. Removing this newline allowed me to search the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem: to fill the table I am reading a textfile per line. The newline character was the problem, it is invisible in phpMyAdmin's browse table view, but I saw it when editing a single row.

The following query fixed my problem:

```
UPDATE Types SET Type = REPLACE(REPLACE(Type, '\r', ''), '\n', '');
```

Found in [How to remove new line characters from data rows in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504962/how-to-remove-new-line-characters-from-data-rows-in-mysql)

Thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: I think that's better if you mark it as solved, so the next guy that comes here with the same problem can also be helped :-)

Comment: Can't do that before 2 days are over, wanted to do it right away... Will do it asap.

Comment: Very Thanks, It works like charm. I have been struggling for last 2 weeks this issue. Thank you very much. +1

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that's due to trim

Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM Types WHERE  TRIM(Type) = 'S 1000 RR'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no results

Answer (score 0):

Its not like that. Your table name and column names are all good and the query is also giving correct o/p:
go
CREATE TABLE Types
   ( 
   ID int,
    Name varchar(3), 
    Type varchar(9));

go
INSERT INTO Types
    (ID, Name, Type)
VALUES
    (1, 'BMW', 'S 1000 RR')

```
SELECT * FROM Types WHERE Type = 'S 1000 RR'
```

Comment: It was a newline character at the end that screwed it up. See my answer for details.

Comment: okok..i was tryin in ssms actually