# InnerHTML linebreaks with a string that is very long with line breaks, coming from a MYSQL query

Tags: javascript, html

I have a for loop in which I am printing out content on a web page. Anything with a line break in the database will not work with innerHTML.

Here is the process of how to get a string from the db: 
1. Submit a form with text thats gets queried into the database. 
2. For loop which displays all the contents in the database using an array,
say $content[i].

value.innerHTML works with any strings that don't have a line break. 
For example, in the db:
Hello
there
----- Will not work. 
Hello there 
----- Will work.
I have tried using regexes to get a line break and change them to br and such, but inner html will not display content with line breaks. Only those without.

My code that I am using:

```
var commentSection = document.createElement("div");
var str = '<?php echo $comment['contents'];?>';
str = str.replace(/\r\n?|\n/g, '<br />');
var userCommentData = document.createElement("div");
userCommentData.innerHTML = str;
commentSection.appendChild(userCommentData);
```

And a more clearer picture of the error I am having: 
[A step of a query string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwvDB.png)

Comment: Perhaps you could split the text by newlines and insert a paragraph for each item in the list instead?

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/kristofferostlund/pen/KmRQrW

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should loop through the string and do content.innerHTML += someline? Is there perhaps a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @kristofferostlund To understand correctly, what you are doing is you are looping through the string you have and appending them to innerHTML? In my case, I could just do innerHTML+= str since I want it all to be under one div essentially as I am not using a paragraph.

Comment: Not really, for each line I'm inserting a `<p>` with their respective innerHTML as their line. I.E. `<div><p>line 1</p><p>line 2</p><div>`. But it may not really be what you're looking for?

Comment: Oh, a way you could actually retain the exact formatting is to style the div with `white-space: pre`, I've update the pen with this: https://codepen.io/kristofferostlund/pen/KmRQrW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following functions:

- [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities
- [`nl2br`](http://www.php.net/nl2br) Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

Or maybe change your sql query with [TRIM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504982/3819411) function as used in link

Comment: Hi Yashar, I do use htmlspecialchars() before a text is put in the database. I have also tried nl2br with no effect. I know that innerHTML doesn't like new lines, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I added to my answer

Comment: Ok this was the answer. I TRIM the content before putting the query in. This is a temporary fix as I now need to figure out how to add line breaks in, because this simply removes all new lines and puts it in a long line, where essentially I'd like to see paragraphs clearly separated.

Comment: It's glad for you and me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use backtick character ( ` ) for multiline string in javascript.

use this line {  Replace backtick with ( ` ) }

> var str = backtick  <?php echo $comment['contents'];? > backtick ;

insted of this line

> var str = '<?php echo $comment['contents'];? >';