# How to find unknown character in mysql or in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multibyte-characters

First I created database with `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation and created table with same collation. Then I import csv file with

```
load data local infile '/mnt/c/Users/justi/Desktop/enml/enml.csv' 
into table dict 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
fields terminated by '\t' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Sample data

```
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| # id   | english_word   | part_of_speech | malayalam_definition            |
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| 174569 | .net           | n              | പുത്തന്‍ കമ്പ്യൂട്ടര്‍ സാങ്കേതികത ഭാഷ      |
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| 116102 | A bad patch    | n              | കുഴപ്പം പിടിച്ച സമയം               |
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| 219752 | a bag of bones | phr            | വളരെയതികം മെലിഞ്ഞ വ്യക്തി അഥവാ മൃഗം |
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
```

I check with
`SELECT malayalam_definition from dict;`
then `var_dump($row);` gives

```
array(1) { ["malayalam_definition"]=> string(19) "ശരശയ്യ " }  
 array(1) { ["malayalam_definition"]=> string(22) "പൂമെത്ത " }  
 array(1) { ["malayalam_definition"]=> string(41) "സുഖകരമായ അവസ്ഥ " }   
  array(1) { ["malayalam_definition"]=> string(44) "അസുഖകരമായ അവസ്ഥ " }   
  array(1) { ["malayalam_definition"]=> string(22) "പൂമെത്ത " } 
  array(1) { ["malayalam_definition"]=> string(123) "സുഖകരമെങ്കിലും സ്വാതന്ത്യ്രമില്ലാത്ത അവസ്ഥ " }
...
```

You can find an unknown character after each word like `"ശരശയ്യ "`. 
I tried `select trim(malayalam_definition) from dict` but gives same result. how to find out that character after each words?

Comment: good question, i want to know answer as well

Comment: That's probably some trash from the csv file.

Comment: Can you try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504962/how-to-remove-new-line-characters-from-data-rows-in-mysql and see if it helps.

Comment: @NigelRen Tried, gives same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the string to hex is one way:

```
SELECT HEX(malayalam_definition),CONCAT("{",malayalam_definition,"}")
FROM dict
WHERE id=116102
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '") FROM dict WHERE id=116102"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` direct query gives `E0B495E0B581E0B4B4E0B4AAE0B58DE0B4AAE0B48220E0B4AAE0B4BFE0B49FE0B4BFE0B49AE0B58DE0B49A20E0B4B8E0B4AEE0B4AFE0B4820D
` and `{കുഴപ്പം പിടിച്ച സമയം
}`

Comment: yes, the quotes need to be adjusted for your php quoting context.

Comment: Did you see any problem in hex value? When I converted it, I get `കുഴപ്പം പിടിച്ച സമയം
`. If you see closely There is a space I doubt?

Comment: Found it `0D`. This value is the unknown character. What is this value? Is it a space? `\r`?